# Потеря согласованности между react-компонентом и его состоянием в родителе

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Разрабатываю свое первое приложение на react-e, текущая версия которого [здесь](https://medsched.online/), а гит [здесь](https://github.com/lpvmak/med_sched/tree/develop/app).

В основе лежит App компонент-функция с состоянием

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState({
        drugs: [{}],
        numOfForms: 1
    });
```

, внутри которого рендерятся Form компонент-функции в количестве, зависимом от `numOfForms`.

Стокнулся с проблемой после реализации кнопки удаления формы:

```
 function handleDeleteForm(index){
        let form = formValues.drugs;
        form.splice(index, 1);
        setFormValues(formValues => ({
            drugs: form,
            numOfForms: (formValues.numOfForms -= 1)
        }));
    }
```

Здесь я по индексу удаляю объект в массиве форм в состоянии, а затем заново выполняется рендеринг меньшего количества форм.
Проблема: React просто не выполняет рендеринг "последней" из форм, а не той, которую я удалил состоянии. В результате состояние в App расходится с тем, что лицезреет пользователь, хотя, как мне казалось, такого быть не может.

Скриншоты:

1) Изначальная картина
[image: Изначальная картина]

2) После удаления первой (!!!) формы
[image: После удаления первой (!!!) формы]

Как видите, на экране остается та, которую удалил.

Хотя, поверьте мне, в состоянии App хранятся сейчас единственные данные второй формы (проверял `console.log()` и отработкой скрипта генерации).

Я могу понять: не предусматриваю особенностей реакта или где-то наговнокодил. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Что пробовал:

1. Прокидывать values (по нему идет построение всех элементов) в Form

```
  <Form onChange={handleFormChange}
        onClickDelete={handleDeleteForm}
        index={i}
        numOfForms={formValues.numOfForms}
        values = {formValues.drugs[i]}
  />
```

Не принесло никакого результата.

2. Прокидывать новую пропертю valuesSave таким же образом: упешно прокидываетя, но не смог правильно выполнить синхронизацию.

Меня преследует чувство, что решение проще и я его не вижу в силу своей неопытности. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: добавь пожалуйста код компонентов..и как ты их генеришь

Comment: @СергейПетрашко я могу добавить, но там выйдет довольно много, может лучше на гите глянешь?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко [app](https://github.com/lpvmak/med_sched/blob/develop/app/src/components/App.component.js) , [form](https://github.com/lpvmak/med_sched/blob/develop/app/src/components/Form.component.js)

Comment: у меня всё нормально удаляется...

Comment: @RTW , десять минут назад обновил девелоп и залил на сервер. Мне подсказали как исправить друзья. В течение двух часов напишу кратко решение.

Answer (score 0):

> Меня преследует чувство, что решение проще и я его не вижу в силу своей неопытности.
>   Не без помощи ребят с опытом проблему решил, и, как оказалось, чувство, не подвело.

Проблема крылась в нарушение азов: присваивал компонентам-формам "уникальные" значения key, которые были вовсе не уникальные -- как только происходило удаление одной из форм, key сдвигалось и уже отрисовало не то.

Так, теперь в состоянии в массиве объектов форм хранился так же реально уникальный индекс, который генерировал как `Date.now()`. Передавал соответственно теперь уже реально уникальный ключ:

```
<Form onChange={handleFormChange}
      onClickDelete={handleDeleteForm}
      keyValue={formValues.drugs[i].id}
      key={formValues.drugs[i].id}
      numOfForms={formValues.numOfForms}
      values = {formValues.drugs[i]}
/>
```

Ну и во всех функциях, параметром в которых был ключ, выполняю поиск индекса данной формы в массиве:

```
let arrIndex = 0;
for (arrIndex; arrIndex < formValues.numOfForms; arrIndex++){
    if (formValues.drugs[arrIndex].id === key){
        break;
    }
}
```

Собственно, все.

Comment: Полезный совет: всегда менять state 1 раз сразу на новое значение; 1.Получить state в свою переменную, - 2. обработать, - 3. заменить state; Это гарантирует 1 ререндер компонента